# AdaBoost: Why does test error decrease even after training error hits zero?

Tags: error, adaboost

After applying AdaBoost to the [Sonar data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Connectionist+Bench+%28Sonar%2C+Mines+vs.+Rocks%29), I obtain something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO2Uk.png).

I dont understand that phenomenon, can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: It appears to be related to how *confident* AdaBoost is in correctly classifying the observations. See [Schapiro and Freund's book](http://www.amazon.com/Boosting-Foundations-Algorithms-Adaptive-Computation/dp/0262526034/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1441378334&sr=8-7&keywords=Boosting+%28Adaptive+Computation+and+Machine+Learning%29), p16 has some introductory remarks that point to later chapters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly this question is answered by Schapire and Freund, et. al. in their publication

> Boosting the Margin: A New Explanation for the Effectiveness of Voting
>   Methods Robert E. Schapire, Yoav Freund, Peter Bartlett and Wee Sun
>   Lee The Annals of Statistics Vol. 26, No. 5 (Oct., 1998), pp.
>   1651-1686

The takeaway from all their math is, that even when the training error is zero, the margin (= sample distance to decision boundary) is still improved by further boosting iterations. 
Also, among other things they show that there are lower upper bounds on the generalization error for a classifier with larger margin, which at least supports what you are seeing.