# How does AdaBoost continue to work when its training error reaches zero?

Tags: boosting, adaboost

It's [said](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171093/adaboost-why-does-test-error-decrease-even-after-training-error-hits-zero) that continuing to boost after reaching zero training error can improve test error in AdaBoost.

However, I don't see how the algorithm can continue at all if it is reaching zero training error; $\alpha_i$ will become +inf if the error is zero.

[image]